# Date object using string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string date coming from a server and wanted to see if there was a way to get a JS date object from it.

Example: format mm/yy

```
exDate = "0919"
```

I want to return a new date object with the last day of the month also added to it. So for example the above would return

```
Mon Sep 30 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Is the above possible with just a 2 digit year and returning the last day in the month with the date object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse in the string to a date object specifying the month ahead and `0` for the date:

```
var t = new Date("20" + exDate.substring(2, 4), exDate.substring(0, 2), 0);
```